# What does #[+] mean?

Tags: scheme

What `#[]` means in Scheme?

```
>>> +
#[+]
```

Does it mean, that everytime we type a operator to the interpreter, it will return an expression with `#[]`?

Answer (score 1):

When Scheme *printer* uses `#` it means, that what follows is something special and probably can't be read back (you can't copy-paste result into REPL and expect it to work).

There are no operators in Scheme. `+` is a function. When you enter it into a REPL, Scheme returns human readable representation of this function. Exact format is implementation dependant. For example in Guile Scheme:

```lisp
> +
#<procedure + (#:optional _ _ . _)>

> sqrt
#<procedure sqrt (_)>
```